# Is it possible to deploy an Azure AD app to another Office 365 account?

Tags: php, azure, office365api, office365-apps, office365-restapi

In Azure Active Directory, I have registered an App, which allows users to sign in and place items in another users calendar. This app gives me a Client ID, Secret, reply URL etc. These are used within a PHP webapp, where a user signs in using their credentials, then using our own interface allows users to place items in another users calendar.

I am doing this on a development account, xxxxx.onmicrosoft.com.

Is it possible for me to deploy this app to a clients office 365/AD account? Or do I need the client to register their own app and then provide me with Client ID, Secret etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is called a Multi Tenant application, it is one of the options in the page where you manage your application. There is a whole sample [here](https://github.com/OfficeDev/O365-WebApp-MultiTenant)